# laravel 5 urlgenerator with Form::open route with Route Annotations

Tags: laravel, routes, composer-php, illuminate-container, laravel-annotations

I'm using **Laravel 5** with ***Route Annotations***. (The app\Http\route.php will be automaticaly deleted). For video about Route Annotations, you may have a look at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sOvgw40Dg4A

I build  a ***ContactController.php*** with ***php artisan make:controller ContactController***

And at ***store()*** function, I add ***return view('pages.contact');*** to re-input another contact data.

When I give the script below on my pages\contact.blade.php :

```
{!! Form::open(['route'=>'contact.store']) !!}
```

It allways return error as below :

```
ErrorException in UrlGenerator.php line 237: Route [contact.store] not defined. (View: D:\www\mycontact\resources\views\pages\contact.blade.php)
```

which refer to :

> ```
> public function route($name, $parameters = array(), $absolute = true)
> {
>   if ( ! is_null($route = $this->routes->getByName($name)))
>   {
>       return $this->toRoute($route, $parameters, $absolute);
>   }
>
>   throw new InvalidArgumentException("Route [{$name}] not defined.");
> }
> ```

But when I change into :

```
{!! Form::open(['url'=>'contact']) !!}
```

it works normally.

How to fix my laravel so I can use the route ?

Below are the things that I have done :

```
composer require illuminate/html
```

At config\app.php , I add : ***'Form'       => 'Illuminate\Html\FormFacade'*** so I can use the {!! Form:: !!}

Then I execute the following command :

```
composer update
composer dump-autoload 
php artisan dump
php artisan clear-compiled
php artisan dump-autoload
php artisan optimize
php artisan route:clear
php artisan route:scan
php artisan route:list
```

So... How to fix my laravel so in my blade, I can use ***{!! Form::open(['route'=>'contact.store']) !!}*** instead ***{!! Form::open(['url'=>'contact']) !!}*** ?

PS: 
I use XAMPP on Windows 7 Pro 64bit.
And I already read : http://laravel.io/forum/10-11-2014-forms-doesnt-work-in-laravel-5

For my steps on Route Annotations, at App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider.php , I add my controllers with in

```
protected $scan = [
  'App\Http\Controllers\HomeController', // for http://localhost/myl5/
  'App\Http\Controllers\ContactController',  //  for http://localhost/myl5/contact
];
```

Comment: Try `contact/store` instead of `contact.store`.  Be sure to define the route to the ContactController in the routes folder

Comment: Did you set up the route in App/Http/routes.php? If not add the route and the method you want or you can do the `$router->Controller('/contact','ContactController');`  Don't forget to name the methods if you do it this way to include the method of communication, i.e.: `postStore` or `getStore`

Comment: You need to show what routes you have defined in your `routes.php` file.

Comment: I'm using route annotation. so there is no App/Http/routes.php

Comment: for video about Route Annotation, you may look these video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sOvgw40Dg4A

Comment: @SidhiCiang So show your route annotations

Comment: Ok, I edited my question to describe how I make the Route Annotations in my L5. The route annotations work, so it does with my Controllers. Plus my route.php is being automatically deleted, because I'm using Route Annotations. :)